# Pomelo EF Core Must be reducible node error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am not sure why I am getting the error: "Must be reducible node"

I tried this solution but I got the 'must be reducible node' error.
 I am running Core 2 with EF Core 2.2

```
                try
                {

                    TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(firm.OpeningHours.Split('-')[0].Split(':')[0]), Convert.ToInt32(firm.OpeningHours.Split('-')[0].Split(':')[1]), 0);

                    var totals = await _unitOfWork.Additions.GetAll().Where(x => x.FirmId == firm.FirmId && x.State == false && x.Closing >= opening && x.Closing <= closing)
                    .GroupBy(x =>
                            new {
                                Y = x.Closing.Value.Year,
                                M = x.Closing.Value.Month,
                                D = x.Closing.Value.TimeOfDay >= start ? x.Closing.Value.Day : x.Closing.Value.Day - 1
                            })
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        onKey = Convert.ToDateTime(new DateTime(s.Key.Y, s.Key.M, s.Key.D)).ToShortDateString(),
                        total = s.Sum(c => c.Price)

                    }).ToListAsync();


                    return new BaseResponse<object>(totals);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return new BaseResponse<object>(ex.Message);
                }
```

DB provider which I am using is Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version 2.2.6

Comment: What is the type of `x.Closing`? The error indicates EF Core bug, but most likely is caused by some of the methods/properties used in the query (for instance, `Convert.ToDateTime`, `new DateTime`, `ToShortDateString()` etc.), so in order to give you workaround, we need to be able to reproduce the issue, i.e. at least the code for the `Addition` class.

Comment: @IvanStoev x.Closing type of DateTime

Comment: @IvanStoev Before I added conditional statement in GroupBy, It was working. When I added this statement it did not work.

Comment: Take a look at [must be reducible node](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/search?q=must+be+reducible+node&type=Issues) issues in the EF Core repo.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GroupyBy()` expression is probably not translatable. The line that is unlikely to work is the following one:

```cs
D = x.Closing.Value.TimeOfDay >= start ? x.Closing.Value.Day : x.Closing.Value.Day - 1
```

The problem here is, that SQL does not allow conditional logic inside a `GROUP BY` clause.

You could move the conditional logic in a select clause before the group by clause and then just group on its result:

```cs
var totals = await _unitOfWork.Additions.GetAll()
   .Where(x => x.FirmId == firm.FirmId &&
               x.State == false &&
               x.Closing >= opening &&
               x.Closing <= closing)
   .Select(x => new {
       Y = x.Closing.Value.Year,
       M = x.Closing.Value.Month,
       D = x.Closing.Value.TimeOfDay >= start ? x.Closing.Value.Day : x.Closing.Value.Day - 1
   })
   .GroupBy(x => new {
       Y = x.Y,
       M = x.M,
       D = x.D
   })
// ...
```

This would generally work, but in Pomelo `2.2.6`, there is no translation for `DateTime.TimeOfDay` (it is supported in `3.0.0` though), so you will need to compare the date's `Hour`, `Minute` and `Second` values with the corresponding properties of the `TimeSpan` (the `start` variable) instead.